# I need a potentiometer to swing -/+ 5V

Tags: power-supply, dual

I need to have one "KNOB" that swings a dual power supply (+/- 5V) from balanced (+5 and -5) to 0v +5 or 0V and -5V and of course anywhere in-between.

My first thought is just the +5V connected to one leg, the -5V to the other and the maybe the output would be right, but that seems not very efficient. I need to be able to deliver about 100mA.

Any thoughts? I would prefer not to use DC to DC converters, but am open to suggestions.

Comment: what exactly is `anywhere in-between`?

Comment: Sounds like you need two knobs. "Anywhere in between" sounds like you want independent control of the two outputs.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want a single output which swings between +5V and -5V, or if you want 2 outputs which together swing between +5V and 0V and -5V and 0V, synchronized to each other from a single control input. Which is it?

Comment: Jack, is this supposed to be a dual *tracking* supply that can vary from all the down to 0 V and up to 5 V with a ground and a pair of tracking power outputs that match each other and are controlled by a single knob? You used the word "balanced" and this makes me wonder if you are looking for a +/- tracking supply.

Comment: Two outputs synced to each other, something like a PAN circuit in audio.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach - probably what I’d do since I have those parts laying around. Not necessarily the best overall but would work.

The “easiest” way is not to use a 5V supply. You’ll need a voltage reference - sure, but that can be TL431. All we need is enough current to drive the potentiometer.

After the potentiometer there would be an op-amp follower with a push-pull transistor stage added. The stage should be biased into class AB operation and should be able to drive capacitive loads all by itself. The op-amp will close the loop at low frequencies only. The follower and the output stage will new ±9V or thereabouts.

The output stage can be a DC-coupled audio amplifier stage. An IC would work, otherwise anything simple from Mr Pass and the likes will do just fine. 100mA is not a lot of current - the output stage needs to have 1W capacity. So probably just 4 transistors in the signal path + bias devices.

If you’d like to operate the thing with lower losses, the final stage would need to be common-emitter/common-source. That stage can then run from ±6V. TL07x and LM358 will work fine in this application.

LM386 - yes the audio amp - should be able to be adapted to the role of a DC push-pull driver. Google “LM386 robot motor driver” - it will need about ±7V or ±8V supplies. Make sure to get the LM384N-4 variant as the -1..-3 are only rated for ±6V operation and won’t be happy at 7-8V bipolar.

The potentiometer can be driven from ±2.5V derived from a pair of TL491s connected as Zener diodes. The op-amp will then have gain of 2 and should have enough headroom to work from ±6V supplies.

TL;DR: You’ll want a ±6V..±9V fixed voltage supply, use an “improved” Zener voltage reference, and then have one or two op-amp+discrete output sections that can generate as many independent copies of the voltage on the potentiometer as needed.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to add efficiency to this type of circuit is with a voltage follower:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuJQ0t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Because the inputs to the opamp are high impedance, this draws almost no current through the potentiometer and is therefore more stable and efficient.  The opamp sources the current for your load.

Comment: This is certainly how I would do it.  That said, if the whole +/-5V range is really needed, you'd probably want wider power supplies on the op amp, and not every op amp can handle 100mA on the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a voltage follower power op-amp and pot connected from +5 to -5V.

Eg. you could use an [OPA547](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa547.pdf) power op amp with +/-7 to +/-9V supply rails.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFbyt1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One thing to be cautious of with a general power supply application is that most op-amps, even power ones, are unhappy with capacitive loads connected directly to the output. Some with as little as 100pF have noticeably less phase margin. The OPA547 is okay with **a few nF** but if you have many uF you'll need to add compensation or
you'll have more of an ultrasonic power oscillator than a power supply.

The schematic does not include bypass capacitors from +/-7V to ground near the op-amp, something like 100uF in parallel with 1uF ceramic would be good.